# Error on project

Tags: get, connection

Im getting this error running my project.

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"
```

Anybody had a clue why this is happening?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you post the code that is throwing this exception, someone is more likely to be able to help you.  You can edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 2):

This error could happened for many reasons (and since you don't upload more code its pretty difficult to help you).

**First Possible Reason**

You are getting this error `"no suitable driver"` because the resource referens isn't beed added to the `web.xml` deployment descriptor, so add the following code.

```
<resource-ref> 
<description>Database for IFPWAFCAD application</description> 
<res-ref-name>jdbc/IFPWAFCAD</res-ref-name> 
<res-type>javax.sql.data source</res-type> 
<res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope> 
</resource-ref>
```

**Second possible Reason**

This may be tricky but check that there is not 'blankspace' on your `xml files`

**Third possible reason**

If you are deploying the current app lets call them "testApp" to a Webserver, have in mind that you should copy the `mysql connector` to the lib directory of that web server

Hope this Help You

Comment: thanks. i got the same results again. when i deploy the application, this is what i get as an output in the project console                                                                                                                      compile:
compile-jsps:
Undeploying ...
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Tarus Nicholas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IFPWAFCAD\build\web
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/IFPWAFCAD
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)